# Can't import android.app.Dialog after bad shutdown

Tags: android-studio, import, sdk, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have custom class that extends android.app.Dialog, but after a bad pc shutdown when i was using android studio now i get: Cannot resolve symbol Dialog, with red.

You may say just don't use dialog and use AlertDialog instead, but the problem is even alert dialog is effected and i can't use .show() after creating it, i can only show dialog from builder instance (when i open AlertDialog class i can see app.Dialog also red).

The app run normally without any error even when android studio mark it with red and show no error during building.

All my project have the same problem so i though it's from the sdk.
I tried Clean rebuild, import project.
Tried invalidate cash and restart.
Remove .idea and iml.
I removed the entire sdk and re-downloaded.
I removed and re-downloaded .gradle file in User directory
I upgraded android studio version.
I changed buildToolsVersion and still it say Dialog class doesn't exist

When i open the sdk and go to android.app.dialog jar file i can see the dialog.java file there but android studio doesn't.

I can build i run the app without problem as i said but i can't keep seeing all those red marks in my files i hate that and i need solution.
Do i have to reinstall everything from sdk to android studio? or clean windows install?

[Red Dialog import even when it exist in jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12uAB.png)
[Can't use .show() method from AlertDialog instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXmcR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so finally i deleted C:/users/username/.AndroidStudio3.6 folder with all files in it! Works like charm ! An stupid solution for a stupid problem, btw problem solved ! Thanks everyone !!